# Do Meshes get reloaded when switching scene?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Lets suppose I have a scene with several meshes like trees, boxes, etc. lets call it level 1.

After I finish playing level 1 I switch to level 2 like this.

```
SceneManager.LoadScene (1, LoadSceneMode.Single); //level2 scene index is 1
```

The thing is level 2 uses the same meshes level 1 uses. Do they get unloaded -> reloaded?

I'm not talking about [DontDestroyOnLoad](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html), as I dont need the same instances of the GameObjects in the level 2 scene.

I'm talking about the Model Data of each object (the meshes), not their instances. I know the instances are deleted, but I think Unity someway knows the next scene uses the same Meshes and keeps them. I just need to know if the Meshes are unloaded and reloaded when switching scene.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objects that you don't call `DontDestroyOnLoad` on are destroyed once you change the scene using `LoadScene` (as if you called `Destroy` on them all), so yes the get reloaded. They are destroyed then (if they're present in the next scene) they're re-instantiated.

If you do edits to a specific object instantiated in a scene then these edits belong to this object.

If you load **the same scene** more than once then this specific object will have your edits. However if you load a different scene that has this prefab then the prefab will be a new one without the edits.

If you want all object instantiated to be like this object you have to edit the prefab. To do this you just click the "apply" button.

[image: prefab buttons]

This will make all objects that become instantiated have the edits.

If you want some object to have the edits and some not to have them you make a separate prefab, just drag the "name" of this object from the hierarchy into your project folder. You've just created a new prefab and you can use it.

Also remember that this doesn't apply to edits done within the game. These are edits that you do (as a developer not as a gamer) in the scene view. Game view edits (for example if a player squishes a cube) are lost after game close.

Comment: Are you sure? I'm talking about the Model Data of each object, not their instances. I know the instances are deleted, but I think Unity someway knows the next scene uses the same Model Data and keeps it.

Comment: where do you keep the model data? what what is the model data exactly? aren't they variables?

Comment: If it's something you edit in your prefabs the every prefab instantiated will have the same edits. so the next scene will have your edits. If the edits are made "in run time" throughout the level then those edits will be lost with the new scene. give me more information so that I understand exactly what you're at

Comment: No, what I mean with model data is the data about the 3d model. I'm talking about the polygons etc. For example if you load an .fbx, the contents of it.

Comment: Not unfortunately. I'm not talking about edits done by me nor anything else. I'm talking about the model data. But I appreciate your effort.

Comment: hehe thx no prob :D `The thing is level 2 uses the same objects level 1 uses. Do they get unloaded -> reloaded?` yes they do, they're destroyed and re-instantiated. `I'm talking about the Model Data of each object` The prefab is instantiated from scratch just like you put it in your new scene. Maybe give me an example of the data you're talking about. Object location on the map? Vertices on the object? Materials or colour of the object? A variable on a script attached to object?

Comment: vertices on the object.

Comment: okay so `level 2 uses the same objects level 1 uses` They'll all have the same "original" arrangement of vertices. However if you edit the model in level 1, the model in level 2 won't be affected *(unless you use the Apply button discussed above. This button saves the changes to the prefab itself.)*

Comment: Try this: make a sphere. Drag the sphere from hierarchy to your project folder. You've just made a prefab! Drag that prefab back to scene view. You re-instantiated the prefab and you have two spheres. Resize one of those spheres in scene view. The other doesn't get affected. Hit "Apply". The other is affected.

Comment: you dont understand my question xd

Comment: I know all about gameobjects and teir components, their variable and etc. What I want to know is, if the scene 2 uses the sames meshes than scene 1, do they get reloaded?

Comment: If they use the same mesh it'll stay the same across all scenes. However if a scene modifies the mesh, these modifications are not saved and will be destroyed when the scene changes .. even if the same scene is loaded again, the object will be reloaded without the changes

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was asking, forgot to comment about it 2 (almost 3) years ago :)